# Mulitple line plots in one graph in R

Tags: r, histogram

I am new to R. I would like to create a plot in R by combining all the data in one graph with colour curves and legends.

My data file is in zipped format: http://www.datafilehost.com/d/e115550e

As I am beginner in R, I have learned to create one curve

> $R
>
> curve_17 <- read.table("samp_17.txt")
>
> plot(curve_17[2:50,],type="l")

which produced one curve. But I need to combine all data samp_17.txt, samp_25.txt and samp_30.txt in one graph as given below

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, what you did with `plot` is not a [histogram](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Histogram). It is just the plot of your data. You can try something like this:

```
> curve_17 <- read.table("C:/.../samp_17.txt")
> curve_25 <- read.table("C:/.../samp_25.txt")
> curve_30 <- read.table("C:/.../samp_30.txt")
> 
> plot(curve_17[2:50,],type="l",ylim=range(curve_17[2:50,],curve_25[2:50,],curve_30[2:50,]))
> points(curve_25[2:50,],type="l",col="blue",lwd=2)
> points(curve_30[2:50,],type="l",col="red",lwd=3)
> legend("topright",col=c("black","blue","red"),legend=c("curve_17","curve_25","curve_17"),lty=rep(1,3),lwd=1:3)
>
```

[image]

Comment: It's not incorrect, but `points(..., type="l",... )` is slightly incoherent. Why not use `lines()` instead?

Comment: With `points` you can change the plotting character i.e. by changing the `pch` argument. But you I don't think that you can do this with lines. So you have more flexibility wiht `points` than `lines`. One more thing, publihsers normally publish papers in black and whites. But with lines you just left with `lty` and `lwd` argument to change. The `points` function is much more useful at least based on my experience.

Comment: 1) But you're not plotting characters here, and in any case `lines` takes a `pch` parameter, at least in some cases (e.g. `type="b"`). 2) Since the y-values are counts, if the counts are from binned data (as it seems they may be), they would effectively be histograms, just with bins so narrow you wouldn't see bars, so the centers of the tops are joined by straight lines instead (a frequency polygon, in effect, but it seems common to call these histograms in some areas of science; the underlying calculation is of a histogram, even if the display isn't).

Comment: thanks stat. If I want to multiply first column by second column and If I want to plot first column and multiplied third column, how can I do that?.